# Flutter Posting Image to API

Tags: flutter, api

I'm trying to post an image through an API with flutter
This is my ImagePicker method :

```
File uploadimage;

Future chooseImage() async {
var choosedimage =
    await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final File convertedimage = File(choosedimage.path);
setState(() {
  uploadimage = convertedimage;
});
}
```

and this is my post method using Dio :

```
  Future upload(
File file,
String refProduit,
String nomProduit,
double prixAchatProduit,
double prixVenteProduit,
String descriptionProduit,
double stockProduit,
) async {
String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
print(fileName);

FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
  "imageProd": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    file.path,
    filename: fileName,
  ),
  "data": jsonEncode({
    'refProd': refProduit,
    'nomProd': nomProduit,
    'prixAchat': prixAchatProduit,
    'prixVente': prixVenteProduit,
    'descriptionProd': descriptionProduit,
    'stock': stockProduit,
  })
});

Dio dio = new Dio();

await dio
    .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/produit',
        data: data, options: Options(contentType: 'multipart/form-data'))
    .then((response) {
  var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.toString());
}).catchError((error) => print(error));
}
```

whenever i try to post the image in my application i get this error in the debug console :

```
Error: Unsupported operation: MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,it ocurs only with flutter-web. You have to use a stream instead of ".fromFile".

postObject is an object of my own document class... I use the property stream to store the stream from filepicker... I'm sure imagepicker has also a function for streams.

MultipartRequest

```
 _asyncFileUpload(String option,dynamic postObject) async{
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST",  Uri.parse("https://example.com"));
    request.headers.addAll(
        {'Accept': '*/*',
          'X-Requested-With':'MultipartRequest',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});

    var file =await http.MultipartFile("file", postObject!.stream, postObject!.bytes, filename: postObject!.name);

    //add multipart to request
    request.files.add(file);
    var response = await request.send();

    //Get the response from the server
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);

    return responseString;
  }
```